# Illegal array key

Tags: php, arrays

This function

```
function convert($size) {
  $unit = array(
    'B',
    'KByte',
    'MByte',
    'GByte',
  );
  return round($size / pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) . ' ' . $unit[$i];
}
```

works but PHPStorm says

> Illegal array key type on line 54

that means $unit[$i].

What's wrong with this function?

Comment: First guess - PHPStorm sees that `floor` returns a float, and using a float as an array key is usually a no-no. Be advised that some other functions, like `array_key_exists`, will actually [produce a runtime error](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/b8525baecf6cfcda385a48c88c8e3da5ac7e5edc/ext/standard/array.c#L4445) if you pass that `$i` as the key, based solely on its type.

Comment: Where did you define `$i`?

Comment: @putvande `($i = floor(...`

Comment: Ow yeah.. Missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`floor`](http://php.net/floor) returns a float, not an integer. (Counter-intuitive, but true.) Floats are illegal keys in PHP arrays.

The code works fine, because [floats are implicitly cast to integers when used as keys in an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), but I imagine that is why you are getting the notification in PHPStorm.

Comment: I fixed it now with $unit[(int)$i] and the notification is gone.